How to fetch call logs in .NET MAUI for Android and iOS
I am developing a .NET MAUI application and I need to fetch the call logs from a user's device. in Android and iOS . and show the caller name and duration of the call in my app .
I have written the following code for Android, but I am encountering an error when trying to query the call logs.
My Questions
How can I resolve the error related to Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query?
Is there a better way to fetch call logs in .NET MAUI for Android?
Is there any better way for iOS to handle call-related features?
My Environment

.NET MAUI
Android
Visual Studio 2022

Code Snippet
public IEnumerable<CallLogEntry> GetCallLogs()
{
    var callLogs = new List<CallLogEntry>();

    var uri = CallLog.Calls.ContentUri;
    string[] projection = {
        CallLog.Calls.Number,
        CallLog.Calls.Type,
        CallLog.Calls.Date,
        CallLog.Calls.Duration,
        CallLog.Calls.CachedName
    };

    using (ICursor cursor = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, CallLog.Calls.Date + " DESC"))
    {
        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                var number = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Number));
                var type = (CallType)cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Type));
                var date = new DateTime(cursor.GetLong(cursor.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Date)));
                var duration = cursor.GetLong(cursor.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Duration));
                var name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CachedName));

                callLogs.Add(new CallLogEntry
                {
                    Number = number,
                    Type = type,
                    Date = date,
                    Duration = duration,
                    Name = name
                });
            } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
        }
    }

    return callLogs;
}

Issue
I am getting the following error:
Error: 'Android.App.Application' is not found. Are you missing any reference assembly?
What I've Tried
I have the necessary permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

Tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.

You can try to use global :: Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query.

An app cannot access call details on iOS. It is a privacy restriction.

Thanks, @LiyunZhang-MSFT! Using global::Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query worked. I appreciate your help!

Thanks, @Paulw11, for pointing that out. I understand that iOS has privacy restrictions that prevent access to call logs.
Are there any alternative approaches or APIs that I can use to handle call-related features in an iOS app? For example, is there a way to initiate a call from the app and possibly track call duration?

Not really. You can use a tel uri to start a call but you can't reliably know when it ends. Obviously if your app is a voip app rather than using the inbuilt cellular service it has full knowledge of call details.

Is there any better way for iOS to handle call-related features? iOS natively does not allow you to do what you are looking for, so I don't think you can really do this at all


I have the necessary permissions in
AndroidManifest.xml:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

For the Android platform, you can use the global :: Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query to get the call logs. Because it based on the Platform.Android, you need to add the global ::.
For the IOS platform, you can not do this due to the apple policy. Apple officially does not expose any public API to access the call log. You can check ths link about the CallKit.
